# Change Image in Widget

Tags: android, widget, imagebutton

How do I have one image in my Widget, then when its clicked change to another image? Its a widget with only an ImageButton, but I'm not sure where to go after this, I know all about pending intents and such, but that doesn't help here, unless I'm missing something... here is my onUpdate

```
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds){
   RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
   PendingIntent onPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, widgetService.class), 0);
   remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageButton01, onPendingIntent);
   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context,AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds){
   RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
   PendingIntent onPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, widgetService.class), 0);

   remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.layout.widget2, onPendingIntent);
                                      **add widgetON.xml*
```

Have a separate .xml layout for the "widgetON" image. (Widget2)
Then, you'd have to mess with remoteViews to distinguish ON/OFF views

I think. :D

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what your looking for

```
 /* get the handle on your widget*/
 RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.your_widget_layout);
 /* replace the image */
 views.setBitmap(R.id.id_of_your_imageview, "setImageBitmap", yourBitmap);

 /* update your widget */
 ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, YourWidget.class);
 AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
 manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
```

Comment: just to clarifiy, you want to do this in onReceiver of your broadcast receiver